# WPF Lync PresenceIndicator control templating

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, lync

I am using PresenceIndicator control in WPF from latest Lync development SDK.

```
                            <controls:PresenceIndicator
                                x:Name="Presence" 
                                Source="sip:test@xyz.com" 
                                PhotoDisplayMode="Large"/>
```

Even though it is latest, it has looks for office 2010.
I tried to edit its template using Blend as show in video from below link, but as soon as i provide any style to PresenceIndicator is somehow looses ability to show lync pictures.

[video to edit template](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Use-Re-Templating-to-Change-the-Appearance-of-a-ContactCard-Control)

Anyone ever noticed this issue ? I think other people also faced same issue, but not sure if they have resolved it or not.

[Other people facing same issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/356d6fec-4978-44c3-b107-5412b61fc1fc/how-to-style-lync-2013-sdk-presence-indicator-so-it-looks-like-lync-2013-flat-presence-square?forum=communicatorsdk)

Anyone ever tried to give flat looks to PresenceIndicator ? Please help.

Comment: anyone ever tried this ?

Comment: I tried, but did not succeed. In the end I rebuild a PresenceIndicatorControl from scratch, which worked out great (but unfortunately I can't share, since it is company property)